# AWS S3 callout fails with x-amz headers

Tags: authentication, namedcredentials, amazon-s3

I have to use canned ACL header 'x-amz-acl' as described in [AWS S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax)

Callout with Named Credentials without header works fine

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:MY_S3/path');
request.setMethod('PUT');
request.setBody(content);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

But if I add header to request

```
request.setHeader('x-amz-acl', 'bucket-owner-full-control');
```

it fails with **SignatureDoesNotMatch** error.
Actually, any header with prefix 'x-amz-' causes signature mismatch.

If there any way to use Named Credentials authentication with canned ACL for S3?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but give the [bigassforce/aws-sdk](https://github.com/bigassforce/aws-sdk) for Salesforce a look. It simplifies a lot of AWS API interactions.

Comment: The header must be part of the signature, this sounds like a bug in Named Credentials implementation of AWS V4 sig. You should open a support case with Salesforce and let them know. In a vanilla S3 implementation, the bucket owner has full control so `bucket-owner-full-control` is not needed. If this is a made-up example and you have some other setup, you can still work around this on AWS side with (for example) a bucket policy.

Comment: @nbrown, thank you for suggestion. I sow this project but it's not completely open source - at least, I  can't find implementation of SDK class. Also, it didn't pass security review. So I don't think I can use it in our project.

Comment: @identigral, unfortunately, I have no control of S3 bucket. It's configured for cross-account access and bucket owner require this ACL in request. I'll try to raise ticket as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Haven't tried this but worth a shot: if you check `Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header` and then merge your value into the header, it might force the header into the signature. It might even work without the actual merge, a mere check might do it.